# Creating your own syntax highlighting in GEdit?

Tags: c, linux, gnome, gedit

How do you add a 'keyword' to the GEdit list of keywords? I basiclly want to make the printf function look like a keyword.

```
printf("Hello World\n");
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/353391/custom-gedit-syntax-highlighting-for-dummies/354684

Answer (score 38, accepted):

GEdit uses [GtkSourceView](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/) for its syntax highlighting. You should be able to find the `c.lang` file it uses to highlight C code by typing a command like this:

```
$ locate gtksourceview | grep /c.lang
```

Once you find the lang file, open it up in a text editor (it's an XML file) and near the bottom you'll see a list of keywords which you should be able to add `printf` to.

Comment: do you know if this file is also named c.lang in gedit for mac? It should be, but when I searched for this file in finder nothing was found...

Comment: I made a copy of c.lang and renamed it into proglang.lang, changed <language id="c" _name="C" version="2.0" _section="Sources"> into <language id="proglang" _name="ProgLang" version="2.0" _section="Sources">. While it shows up in the menu, it won't highlight anything. Why is that? Is there some registry like thing needed to be done here?

Comment: sudo gedit /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/c.lang

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to Jeremy's post I found this page: [Projects/GtkSourceView - GNOME Wiki!](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView) or [GtkSourceView - Documentation (from Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111207025517/http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/documentation.html)

Here you'll find a link to both a tutorial and the official reference for the language definition files.

update: Another useful link [Gedit/NewLanguage - GNOME Live! (from Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111227080157/http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/NewLanguage)