# Document and control FIXME and TODO hightlighting of Perl comments by gedit?

Tags: perl, gedit

When editing a Perl file, [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) 2.30.3 highlights `FIXME`, `TODO` and `XXX` when they appear in a comment. Where is this documented? How can this be modified?

Comment: You might find this question insightful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766775/creating-your-own-syntax-highlighting-in-gedit

Comment: From Ether's link, `grep FIXME $(locate gtksourceview | grep /perl.lang)`, I found nothing defining the handling of FIXME.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's documented here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html
Do a search for "in-comment".

You can do modifications in the def.lang file located in /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs if you're on Ubuntu.

Run a search for "comment-note" and you'll see where the regex is declared.

Comment: `def.lang` rather than `perl.lang` defines these values within a comment to get special highlighting: "FIXME|TODO|XXX".