# Gedit, smart C syntax highlighting

Tags: c, linux, gedit

I'm not much of a full-fledged IDE man. I like minimal, intuitive editors, and use the command-line for anything else.

I've been using Gedit for ages, and just wondered -- there's ONE feature I would like. I'd like the syntax highlighting to recognize `typedef`s and color them when used as types.

Do you guys know of any plugin that does this?

Comment: I like `vi` too, but the OP said *minimal, intuitive*

Comment: @pavium: what's unintuitive about 'vi'?  You type the `l` key to move the cursor right; what could be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766775/creating-your-own-syntax-highlighting-in-gedit). This thread talks about adding syntax highlighting for specific keywords in gedit. You need to run the command given therein as sudo, and edit the file which looks like an xml file. But I do realize that for you need something that is more general than that.