# Creating Gedit syntax files

Tags: shell, gedit, fish

I have started a new thread rather then reviving this one:

[Creating your own syntax highlighting in GEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766775/creating-your-own-syntax-highlighting-in-gedit)

Hope that was the right thing to do. I have created a syntax file for fish shell and placed it in /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs (in Ubuntu). When I open a .fish file with gedit there is no highlighting and the view-->high light mode menu does not show this fish as an option. Is there something that needs to be updated to allow the file to be recognized?

Thanks for reading-Patrick

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are in fact using Gedit 2 and not Gedit 3 (which uses gtksourceview-3.0). For the newer, 3.0 lang files, you can put them into ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-spec/

If you've installed it to the correct location, you should see the name you specified in the _name attribute in the View > Highlight Mode menu under the sub menu you specified with the _section attribute in your .lang file. For example, if I had test.lang with:

```
<language id="test" _name="Test Language File" version="2.0" _section="Markup">
```

Then I would see "Test Language File" under View > Highlight Mode > Markup in the Gedit menu.

Comment: Another way to check to see (at least, in 3.x) is to launch `gedit` from the terminal - it will dump a note if there is an error trying to load

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/`, you could try putting it in `~/.gnome2/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/`.

Assuming you've restarted gedit after installing your syntax file, then it may just be a syntax error. Try installing the Go syntax file (http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/gedit/), and if that shows up but your custom one still doesn't, then it's a problem with your file. If none of them show up, then you may need to re-install gedit or gtksourceview.

Also, make sure the permissions on your new file match those of the existing ones. I doubt gedit would need more than read permissions to be able to use the file, but it wouldn't hurt to check.