# openmp syntax highlighting in gedit?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gedit, intel-fortran

I am facing an awkward situation. I am trying to run a Fortran 90 program in Linux with ifort and since it has OpenMP directives I compile it with the `-openmp-report1` option to see that whether the blocks have been successfully parallelized.

The problem  is that gedit doesn't recognize the OpenMP directive:

```
!$omp parallel do etc....
```

it treats it as a comment. Anyone has an idea about it? I also tried:

```
C$omp parallel do etc...
```

but in that case it produces a compile-time error. Do I have to enable an option in gedit in order to recognize the OpenMP directives?

I faced the same problem in emacs.

I note that I run successfully the same program with Intel Visual Fortran. In Visual Studio OpenMP directives are properly recognized.

Comment: How do you want the directives to be highlighted? Most editors don't do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/766795/2838364

Comment: The problem is once the syntax parser decides it is a comment, it may be impossible. Maybe you will need to change also the definition of the comments.

Comment: @VladimirF thank you for your reply. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly, the question is how can I make gedit recognize correctly the openmp directives and not treat them as comments?

Comment: Yes, I got that quite well. You will have to edit the parser definitions in the Peter's link.

Comment: Thanks. I located the language specs file in gktsourceview. What exactly do I have to add? Something like <keyword>!$OMP<keyword> in operators, in keywords or somewhere else?

Comment: Well, who knows. You will have to study it and understand the format of the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to define a new style in the `<styles>` section of your language specification:

```
<style>
  <!-- ... -->
  <style id="openmp-directives" _name="OpenMP directives" map-to="def:preprocessor"/>
</styles>
```

Next, add a corresponding `<context>` to the `<definitions>` section:

```
<definitions>
  <!-- ... -->
  <context id="openmp-directives" style-ref="openmp-directives" end-at-line-end="true">
    <start extended="true">
      ((^[Cc])|^\s*!)\$
    </start>
  </context>
  <!-- ... -->
</definitions>
```

Activate the evaluation of the new style:

```
<definitions>
  <!-- ... -->
  <context id="fortran" class="no-spell-check">
    <include>
      <context ref="openmp-directives"/>
    </include>
  </context>
  <!-- ... -->
</definitions>
```

Finally, as @VladimirF pointed out, you need to tell GtkSourceView to not treat the directives as comments.

Locate the `<context id="line-comment" ...>` and change

```
<start>!|(^[Cc](\b|[^OoAaYyHh]))</start>
```

to

```
 <start>(![^$])|(^[Cc](\s|[^$OoAaYyHh]))|(^[Cc]$)</start>
```

I just proposed this patch to GtkSourceView [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730130).

Comment: Just FYI: This patch has been [merged upstream](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/commit/?id=85787b25dfc418ef3d3572f17b74228793e99225)...

Comment: Since when has `!$` become an OpenMP sentinel? The only standard-recognised sentinel in free-format sources is `!$omp` (+ case variations) with `*$omp` and `c$omp` additionally recognised in fixed-format files. The sentinel must appear as a single word with no intervening spaces. In fixed-format sources the sentinel must start at position 1.

Comment: @HristoIliev `!$` can be used for Fortran statements that are only validated when OpenMP is enabled... Otherwise, they are treated as comments. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenMP.html).

Comment: One learns new things every day. Thank you! Anyway, `!$` starts a conditionally compiled statement, not an OpenMP directive as stated in the example file (part of the commit you have linked to).