# custom text color for c struct in gedit

Tags: c, struct, colors, themes, gedit

I have a couple structs typedef'd in my code, and I am using them frequently throughout my code. To improve readability, I would like my struct type to have its own text color, just like an int or char would. Is there a way to do this in gedit?

for example:

```
typedef struct  
    {
        int m;
        float v;
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    } body;

int n;
body x;
```

"int" will be colored blue in my theme, but "body" has the same color as a variable name.
this is making my code increasingly difficult to read.

thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

[Creating your own syntax highlighting in GEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766775/creating-your-own-syntax-highlighting-in-gedit)

You just have to add a keyword that is the name of your struct.

I personally would try using a proper IDE instead of a text editor like gedit though.